Expo SDK 51. Console logs not showing up after creating a development build
Since Expo is pushing to use development builds instead of Expo Go, I tried to make one and now I can't see any console.log() in terminal (after pressing a button).
If more info is needed please tell me.
My enviroment:
node: 20.15.0
npm: 10.8.1
Android 14

"dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.45.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.25",
    "expo-constants": "^16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "^12.0.9",
    "expo-image-picker": "^15.0.7",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.52.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-notifier": "^1.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "yup": "^1.4.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.21"
  }

eas.json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 10.2.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {             // <-- this is the one I'm using
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "...": "...",
        "...": "..."
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

In order to connect from my phone I have to run npx expo start --tunnel, I've also tried npx expo start --dev-client --tunnel as I've seen in other people's issues but it doesn't work.
